# CsvHelper - ClassMap by index for file with no header errors on read

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I'm using csvhelper 18.0 and am trying to update some code that used 2.8.4.

I have a file that I'm trying to read that has no headers.
I've defined a `ClassMap` to map by index.

I've created the configuration of the CsvReader so `HasHeaderRecord = false`.

When I try to import this file, I get an error that states `There is no header record to determine the index by name`. I'm confused as to why an error is being thrown regarding the header record. The header record does not exist, which is why I am mapping with an index.

Would anyone know how I can read a headerless file and still map to a class?

Here is the class and mapping class:

```
public class TFile
{
    public int Wn { get; set; }

    public string Hiwn { get; set; }

    public string Sync { get; set; }
}

public sealed class TFileMap : ClassMap<TFile>
    {
        public TFileMap()
        {
            Map(m => m.Wn).Index(0);
            Map(m => m.Hiwn).Index(1);
            Map(m => m.Sync).Index(2);
        }
    }
```

Here is the piece of code that throughs the error:

```
 using (TextReader textReader = new StringReader(data))
        {
            var csvT = new CsvReader(textReader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            csvT.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
            csvT.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<TFileMap>();
            csvT.Configuration.CultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-AU");

            // error occurs on this line
            tData1 = csvT.GetRecords<TFile>().ToList();

         }
```

Here is a small sample file:

```
37,1R,Y
38,1L,Y
39,2R,Y
40,2L,Y
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you please try like this `csvT.Context.RegisterClassMap<TFileMap>();` and remove `csvT.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<TFileMap>();`. I see this in documentation here https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/mapping-by-index

Comment: @Karan That doesn't work - I'm using an old version of CsvHelper it's possible the function was moved. Maybe this is a sign I should be updating to the latest...

Answer (score 0):

I pulled CsvHelper version 18.0 and tried with your code and sample data and it worked just fine for me.

```cs
    var data = @"37,1R,Y
38,1L,Y
39,2R,Y
40,2L,Y";

    using (TextReader textReader = new StringReader(data))
    {
        var csvT = new CsvReader(textReader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        csvT.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
        csvT.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<TFileMap>();
        csvT.Configuration.CultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-AU");

        var tData1 = csvT.GetRecords<TFile>().ToList();
        
        tData1.Dump();
    }
```